# Keep flashlight on while in camera

Tags: camera, flashlight

I'm looking to use an old phone (like a Nexus 5 or Honor 5X) as a nighttime security camera with the [Manything app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manything.manythingviewer), but this doesn't seem practical as I just can't get the flashlight working.

I plan to use Macrodroid/Tasker to turn the flashlight on automatically at night (as Manything doesn't natively support it), but the problem is that the flashlight turns off when opening the Manything camera view and can not be turned on while using the camera.

Is there a way to keep the flashlight on while using the camera in Manything? Or is there an Android skin which allows the flashlight to be turned on while the rear flashcamera is active?

Comment: I just tried the app, and it worked with the flashlight that comes with the phone. But when i tried a different flashlight app, it didn't work. So i guess you have to find the right flashlight. I'm using a Galaxy s5

Comment: @Abochur Ooh, sounds promising, S5 it may be then! Could you take a pic (and send it via imgur) of the flashlight working while in the Manything app with the rear camera feed open?

Comment: i could. But i don't think it's going to help you much, because it's the flashlight that comes with my s5, i don't think you'll be able to download it anywhere. Do you still what me to post it?

Comment: @Abochur I mean I'm literally going to buy an S5 for this express purpose :). Could you help me make sure I get one that'll let me use the flash like you can?

Comment: @beeshyams It can be any Android version, I'm planning on buying a new (used) phone for this :). On my own Pixel 2 XL, I've got Oreo and couldn't get flashlight+Manything camera going. And thank you, let me know if you find anything!

Comment: Sorry it looks to more complicated than I thought , I will revert if  I can find a way

Comment: @beeshyams I can root if necessary, but I'd much rather not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a device specific issue. Some phones will allow the flashlight to be on while the camera is on, others won't.

The phone I'm using, Galaxy S5 has no issue with the flashlight that comes preinstalled, being on while the camera is running.

So if you're anyway buying a phone for this, Galaxy s5 or any other phone that allows it, should be your choice. *(In my humble opinion, instead of buying this phone, you're better off buying a security camera with night vision...)*

In the screenshot below, I have the [manything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manything.manythingviewer) app in recording mode, and the flashlight on, and I'm facing a mirror.

[image]

*Using galaxy S5 on AT&T Android 6.0 flashlight widget that comes with the phone.*

Note: other flashlight apps didn't work while camera is on.

I wouldn't post this as an answer had there not been a comment from OP saying:

> @Abochur I mean I'm literally going to buy an S5 for this express
>   purpose :). Could you help me make sure I get one that'll let me use
>   the flash like you can?

Comment: Thanks @Abochur! Just one question before I literally purchase an S5 thanks to you (while I appreciate the suggestion, a night vision camera doesn't quite work for us given a very awkward placement needed!)—is there a way I can automate the turning off/turning on of the camera by time? For instance, is MacroDroid able to turn on the flashlight with a macro while Manything is open? Or maybe I could rig an accessibility service to turn on the flashlight with the widget then enter the Manything app again?

Comment: It's really all about turning on a widget using tasker or MacroDroid. If you have any advice on how it's done with tasker, I'll try it

Comment: It would be awesome if you could try it for me, I'd appreciate it :). The app I'll use is [TouchTask](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.balda.touchTask)—with that installed you can create a new "Task" in Tasker, then search for "Actions" and tap the one with the TouchTask to get started. I'm more than happy to help you help me—I should have no problem setting up that to leave Manything, turn on the magical widget flashlight, and return to Manything, right?

Comment: @owlswipe It looks like it's going to take me some time to figure this one out. But as long as you have an automated way of enabling a widget, I don't think it should be a problem. I'd suggest when buying the phone, that you get one that has a 30 day return policy just in case....

Comment: That's a good call, and thanks much for the advice :). I'll try to pick one up and let you know how it goes!! Thank you!!

Comment: @owlswipe out of curiosity, did you end up purchasing the phone, and if yes, how did it go?

Comment: I'm so sorry to have forgotten!! I got a used S5 just as you suggested and it's working perfectly for my needs::). Thank you!!